# How can I train ARIMA/ARMA model by taking the previous points only at weekly distance?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have many time series data-sets with hourly points. The current model in my organisation is using rough coefficients to forecast the value for the current hour using the value at the same hour-same day previous 8 weeks.

Say the point to be predicted is $X_t$
The current model uses the following for every series-

\begin{align}
X_t = &X_{t-168}0.25 + X_{t-336}0.2 + X_{t-504}0.15 + X_{t-672}0.1 +  \\
      &X_{t-840}0.1 + X_{t-1008}0.1 + X_{t-1176}0.05 + X_{t-1344}0.05
\end{align}

This model produces really good results for some of our series but performance is not good on some other series.

I want to refactor these coefficients(called as AR coefficients in the current code we have) and have different coefficients for each series. How can I do the training to get new *AR* or *AR*,*MA* coefficients of a model which is the same as *~ ARMA(8,8)* where the time grain is 168?

I have tried the forecast package in R but it does not support such large seasonality. Can someone please suggest me an approach or a library which supports changing the time-grain?

Comment: You might be better on an R specific site.

Comment: @mdewey, any suggestions? I'm new to this area.